# How effective was the 2014-2015 influenza vaccination?

Tags: vaccination, infection, influenza

I’m aware that the CDC released [this abysmal report](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/news/updated-vaccine-effectiveness-2014-15.htm) on the effectiveness of this year’s influenza vaccination, including data collected through Jan 30, 2015.

> In practical terms, this means the flu vaccine reduced a person’s risk of having to seek medical care at a doctor’s office for flu illness by 19%.

However, this is missing much (possibly most) of the flu season. Are there more updated numbers on vaccine effectiveness and/or reports that include data from other (non-U.S.) locales with a similar flu season (i.e. temperate Northern Hemisphere)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been no additional reports in the *Morbidity and Mortality Weekly Report*, which was where your original article points to regarding the efficacy of the flu vaccine.

However, the [most recent update](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm6408a2.htm?s_cid=mm6408a2_w) on influenza activity within the United States, which was about a month later than your report, does not suggest there has been any mid-season change in the dominant circulating strains, so the early estimates are likely in the same area.

The one thing that may change this is that a larger number of last season cases of influenza are typically caused by influenza B viruses, as shown in this figure below:

[image]

The low effectiveness of the vaccine against the dominant circulating A strains does not necessarily imply a similarly low effectiveness against the later B strains, especially as B strains [appear to be somewhat more stable](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/weekly/weeklyarchives2014-2015/images/image141.gif).

Comment: Thanks! Maybe update this for us when the data become available?

Comment: @Susan It's definitely possible. It looks like there's about a one-month lag before things show up in MMWR. Though if the answer is "nothing changed" it may very well not appear.

Comment: This prompted another question at biology.SE: [What is the difference between influenza A and B viruses that causes their distinct seasonal patterns?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/31629/9268)